# Chrome extension: run extension's script after all other page scripts have loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and I want to load it after all page scripts have loaded.

Site page consists such code:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="main">All body elements, texts, etc...</div>
  <script>
    window.netflix = window.netflix || {};
    netflix.falkorCache = {"genres":"58"}
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My extension code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  launchPlugin();

  function launchPlugin() {
    console.log(typeof(window.netflix));//I have also tried just `netflix`
    if(typeof(window.netflix)!=='undefined'){
      startNetflixPlayer();
    } else{
      setTimeout(
        function(){
          launchPlugin();
        }, 700);
    }
  }

  //other code...

});
```

But plugin never run `startNetflixPlayer()` because `window.netflix` is always `undefined`. I have also tried to check variable `netflix` but it also returns `undefined`.

At the same time if I try to check `console.log(window.netflix)` in Chrome's developer's console I see the result.
`console.log(typeof(window.netflix))` returns `object`. But after this Chrome extension still doesn't see this variable and returns `undefined`.

I believe I miss something simple but can't understand what exactly.

Any ideas how to access the variable (and object data) from the website using extension's script?

P.S. I have checked this answer also but it's not working for me: 
[chrome extension: run script after page has finished loading javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689144/chrome-extension-run-script-after-page-has-finished-loading-javascript)

Comment: 1. Content scripts run in *isolated world* so you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) and 2. No need for `$(document).ready(function() {` if your content script runs at default setting which is `"run_at": "document_idle"`, 3. The devtools console has a context selector in its toolbar, the default is `Top` which means the page itself, but if you switch it to your extension you'll see `undefined` for the page variables just like your content script does.

Comment: Seems like great advice! Checking it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I learned (thanks to @wOxxOm) – Content scripts in Chrome extensions run in *isolated world* so to access page's variables you need to insert targeted code into the site's page using a content script.

1. You need to create `start.js` (whick will insert targeted code into the site's page) with such code:

   ```
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('content.js');
   s.onload = function() {
     this.remove();
   };
   (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
   ```
2. You need to make changes for `manifest.json`:

   ```
   ...
   "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [ "*://www.yoursite.com/*" ],
        "js": ["start.js"],
        "css": [ "style.css"]
      }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["content.js"],
    ...
   ```
3. Put targeted code to `content.js`. Now you can access any variables from the site's page inside `content.js`.

Comment: FYI, technically speaking, once the code is inserted into a DOM script element it's no longer a *content script*, but simply a page script just like any other page script that doesn't have priviledges of a content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm what privileges do you mean?

Comment: A content script is a part of chrome extension which can access [4 chrome.* API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Page scripts obviously can't do that.